# android studio theme issue

Tags: android-studio, themes

i am having a issue with my theme. I know for sure i am doing something wrong i just cannot find what so i hope for your insides. Now i know there are like a miljon posts about themes and for sure i have not read them all but a lot of them i did.
I do not want anything fancy like choosing your theme i just want the app to follow the system settings for light/dark theme.
So i have a values\themes.xml and a night\themes.xml both with the samen name (AppTheme) and both with as parent "*Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar*".
in both themes.xml files the same set of items (defined in the attrs.xml) just with different color values attached to them.
There is NO "setDefaultNightMode" in my app anywhere and as far as i know the default is "automatic" which is exactly what i want.
However my app only uses the light (values\themes.xml) and never the  night/dark option.
my physical phone has the settings to dark mode but even there the colors keep matching the light theme. which is strange because if a clear all entries from the night\themes.xml the app runs in the emulator but crashes on my phone. That to me pointed out that i does use the night\themes.xml but why do my color not changes then?
if more info is needed please ask. Any help is much appreciated.